# Use of undeclared type ‘UIContainerView’

Tags: ios, uicontainerview

I’m using xcode 7 , I’ve a  storyboard controller with an `UIContainerView`

When I’m trying to create an outlet to the controller there is this error **"Use of undeclared type `UIContainerView`"**

it’s not a bug of xcode 7 because there is the same error on xcode 6

i need to create an outlet because when i switch the segmented control i have to programmatically change the embed of the container

It's an error or i mustn't create an outlet for a container? It's seems that there is not something called `UIContainerView` in the library, it's strange

Comment: A container is ultimately a child View Controller, so if you want to change  at run time then you can add a  viewcontroller  as a child view controller. No need to create IBOutlet for that.

Comment: mm ok i'll try this way :) but excluding this solution i can't ever create an outlet for a container or it's a bug? just for curiosity

Comment: Tag your question with "UIContainerView".  Then read the tag's help text.

Comment: It's not a bug, ContainerView is ultimately adding a view controller as your child view controller which is graphically demonstrated using UIContainerView in storyboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such class called `UIContainerView`. You need to create an outlet of `UIView` and connect that to your container view.

You can switch the content of container view like:

```
// Property
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIView *container;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIViewController *first;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIViewController *second;

// Method that removes first vc from view and shows second vc
// Assumes first and second properties already initialized
- (void)showSecondVC
{
  // Removes first view controller
  [self.first.view removeFromSuperview];
  [self.first willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
  [self.first removeFromParentViewController];

  // Shows second view controller
  [self addChildViewController:self.second];
  [self.second didMoveToParentViewController:self];
  self.second.view.frame = self.container.bounds;
  [self.container addSubview:self.second.view];      
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is confusing because IB lablels it as UIContainerView, but it's type is really just a UIView.

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

UIContainerView is not a class, so you are getting error. Instead use UIView. Container view is actually a concept in storyboard, that allow you to do similar programming stuff:

1. Initialise a second view controller
2. Add it as child view controller
3. Add its view at location of container view with same frame.

When you add a container view then all above stuff is done automatically.
If you want to switch to different view controller then you will create multiple container view. Show and hide container views based on UISegmentedController's selectedIndex