# UIContainerView requires what version of iOS?

Tags: ios, version, uicontainerview

I've been digging online and in Apple's docs, but I can't seem to identify what iOS version is required to use UIContainerView. I'm a little frustrated that this tidbit of information is eluding me...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UIContainerView does not exist as a class.

According to the [about page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/uicontainerview/info) of the `uicontainerview` tag in StackOverflow:

> There is no UIContainerView class, but there is a pattern that uses a UIViewController as a container for one or more ViewControllers. This pattern is also in the Xcode object library with the name Container View.

See, for example, the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31049928/use-of-undeclared-type-uicontainerview):

> There is no such class called UIContainerView. You need to create an outlet of UIView and connect that to your container view.
>
> It is confusing because IB lablels it as UIContainerView, but it's type is really just a UIView.

Comment: No wonder I couldn't find it in the developer docs...  It's adds to the confusion that it's name (UIContainerView) follows the conventions of a class name, including when you pick it from the Xcode object library.  Thanks for the help.  Bill